# Execute cmd command without changing the directory

Tags: ant, cmd

Sorry for stupid question, but I want to execute "ant" command in another directory without changing the current one. Is it possible? I'm in C:\foo and want to run "ant" in C:\bar. I can write

```
cd ../bar
ant
```

but is it possible to do it in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. mic4ael offered to use `-f`, this works but my build fails, probably because it's very complex.

```
start "title" /d C:\bar /b /w "ant"
```

/d *path* - where to execute
/b - in the same window, otherwise new window is opened
/w - wait until this command is finished. Otherwise .bat execution will go forward.

http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

This is suitable for many cases and this is what I've been really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the build file for Ant by using `-f` argument. For example, `ant -f C:\bar\build.xml`

Comment: Thanks! This works, but my build fails. Probably because of very complex structure an/|or libraries.